# MS Outlook table padding too big

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email, padding

Here is how it looks in outlook:

[image]

But it should look like this:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<table style="border-bottom: solid 1px #e5e0d8; background-color: #0f0;" class="content_module" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>

        <td>

            <table style="background-color: #f0f;" class="content_col" width="285" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" align="left">

                <tr>

                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; background-color: #f00;">

                        <!-- img -->

                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>


            <table style="background-color: #00f;" class="content_col" width="285" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="15" align="right">

                <tr>

                    <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; background-color: #00f;">

                        <!-- text -->

                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

It seems like outlook adds 3px padding left and right ... See anyone a error? I already tried if it the problem are spaces but that isn't the case.

Comment: Here is a litmus build https://litmus.com/builder/47eace2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was mso-table-space ...

I removed the cellpadding completely and added `style="border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"` to all tables in the whole mailing.

Answer (score 0):

You must make one table like this;

```
                <table width="480" align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="30" style="border:2px solid black;">
                            Some Text
                        </td>
                        <td width="110" style="border:2px solid black;">
                            Some Text
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: The two tables are for a responsive layout like here https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/#four ... it doesn't work with one table.